# Promise in beforeEach (Nuxt/vue-router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am trying to send POST request before route change to verify user credentials and I ended up implementing that logic in Nuxt plugin. But Nuxt does not wait for the promise to be resolved. How can I do this? I have tried using async/await but the result was the same.

```
export default async ({ app }, inject) => {
  app.router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
    if (app.$cookies.get('JWT')) {
        app.$axios.$post('http://localhost:3000/verify', '2').then((res) => {
          console.log('We are here! This is expected to continue...')
          next()
        })
    } else {
        console.log('No cookie!')
        next(false)
    }
  })
}
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVOzI.png)

*EDIT : ADDED SCREEN SHOT

Comment: I really don't know any nuxt, but I'm still almost certain you want to use a [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, there is a kind of bug (I think so.) where repeatedly clicking on browser's back button can bypass the middleware. (I have tested it.)